# Is there a way to pass multiple instances of one dataset to a reportviewer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

I'm trying to show a report of all vouchers uploaded to the DB. This report contains 2 datasets; voucherSummary and voucherHeader. Every voucher has a header and a summary. Is it possible for me to pass multiple instances of these datasets to the same report, and display each instance on a new page as a new voucher?

I've tried using a foreach loop to add new datasources for the 2 datasets, but it comes up blank when running the program.

```
foreach (VoucherUploadModel model in models) {

   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsVoucherUploadSummary", model.GetVoucherDetailsUploadSummary()));

   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsVoucherUploadHeader", model.GetVoucherUploadHeader()));

   //ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsUserInfo", VoucherUpload.Core.CommitDocumentSetHelper.GetUserInfo()));
}
```